# Что нужно для работы mpiexec?

Tags: c++, mpi

Настроил mpi - установил библиотеку msi согласно [этому руководству](http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowshpc/archive/2015/02/02/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-ms-mpi-program.aspx)
Все вроде получилось - программа работает, но соответсвенно, если запустить ее в Visual Studio будет 1 процесс и толку от MPI нет.

В руководстве сказано запустить ее через командную строку

```
mpiexec -n 2 mympi.exe
```

Соответсвенно сменив директорию перед этим.

mpiexec есть, справка вызывается, файл mpiexec.exe нашел (в переменную PATH он тоже записался).

Однако когда я вызываю вышеуказанную команду ничего не происходит. Аналогично ничего не происходит, если вызвать что-то вроде `mpiexec jhkahskjh`.
Если вызвать `mpiexec -n 2`, говорит, что нужен файл исполняемый, то есть работает утилита.

вот весь код mympi.exe

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mpi.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    printf("works");
    getchar();
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

При запуске в VS выводит `works`, что и ожидалось.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Для начала - вы убедились, что mympi.exe не запускался в принципе? Может быть он просто отработал не таким образом как вы предполагаете?

Comment: @YuriyOrlov я думаю, что он скорее всего запускался и отработал не так как надо в силу неизвестных мне причин.

Comment: "вызываю вышеуказанную команду" - в командной строке? "ничего не происходит" - вообще ничего? Добавьте `print "Hello world."` в mympi.exe.

Comment: @YuriyOrlov обновил вопрос

Comment: @RussCoder, тогда сделайте каким-то образом отслеживание действий mympi.exe - какие параметры принимаются в argv, успешны ли вызовы методов MPI. Через час доберусь домой, смогу подробней посмотреть.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в `getchar();` - если его убрать, то у меня все заработало.
Причина по которой не выводилось `works`, хотя оно идет раньше, чем `getchar();` полагаю в том, что вывод идет не напрямую через консоль, а через MPI, она ждёт когда когда процесс завершит работу либо пошлет сигнал `fflush(stdout);` В этом я не силён, поправьте меня кто-то если я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Да верно. Однако getchar(); должен приводить к зависанию, а у меня он как будто просто игнорирует вызов, то есть не виснет ничего, что с getchar, что без него. Ну да ладно - я на другом компе настроил MPI и все пошло, тут дело в какой-то ошибке системы, если с ней не сталкивался, то понять тяжело. Спасибо за ответ.